# Remove border from alt tag text over an image

Tags: html, css, paypal

I'm trying to remove the border from an alt tag text. I'm using a transparent image for a button in a paypal form, linked through css. The paypal button takes the alt tag as it's button text and puts a border around it. I'm not clear on why this happens but it's what I have to work with from paypal. Apparently I have to use an image. So I'm using a transparent image so I can style it in css to look like my other buttons rather than try and get screen shots of each button state.
[image]

I paired the code down to focus on just the border around the text 'View Cart'.

CSS

```
//link to my transparent button with no text on it
#vyc {
      background-image: url(http://lakenney.com/kenney_lucille-final/images/vyc.png) no-repeat;
  }
//the user agent that is controlling the outer border
user agent stylesheetinput[type="hidden" i], input[type="image" i], input[type="file" i] {
      -webkit-appearance: initial;
      padding: 20px;
      background-color: initial;
      border: dotted;
      border-top-color: red;
  }
//a couple of tags I'm using to try to access the alt tag border not working
#vyc img[alt] {
      /*border: 1px dashed #3D8EA5;*/
      border: transparent !important;
  }
input#vyc img[alt] {
      border: transparent !important;
  }
```

HTML

Here is a jsfiddle link to this same code:
http://jsfiddle.net/lakenney/w0zpmutn/

Comment: I'm using input type="image" because it's a paypal button. I have to use image. So I'm trying to work around that by using input type="image" and linking to a transparent image so I can style it. It all works except I get that border around the alt tag. I'm trying to figure out what css element to use to style the alt tag to that image. Maybe what I'm trying to do is not feasible?

Comment: @humble.rumble Interesting. But once I link to the image in the html, the alt text is no longer visible which makes sense since the role of the alt tag is to take the place of the image if it's missing. Perhaps I would be able to access children of input by traversing the DOM and somehow get my hands on the alt. That might be worth a shot. Or maybe create the transparent image with the text on it then style it with css. That might work. I could always just create the button as an image but I thought there should be a better way. I'm just tossing things around my brain.  :)

Comment: @humble.rumble Putting the image url in the html and using the overlay is going to work for me with a little more tweaking! You are a genius! Thank you! 

http://jsfiddle.net/lakenney/w0zpmutn/

Answer (score 1):

The input(type = "image") expects an src image which missing and hence the border. Is it possible for you to put the transparent image as the src value?

```
<input type="image" src="http://lakenney.com/kenney_lucille-final/images/vyc.png" id="vyc" border="0" name="submit" value="View Cart" alt="View Cart">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w0zpmutn/2/

Comment: This is a tricky one. And I suppose what I'm trying to do is a hack. The image is linked via css. I colored the image so you can see it. But I see now why the alt tag shows because there is no 'src' in the html input. But what I'm trying to do is control that alt tag with css. My problem is, I have to use an image with paypal forms. I'm trying to use a transparent image linked via css so I can style it to look like my other buttons. And I could get it to work if I could hook into the alt tag and style that. Perhaps that's not possible?

Comment: My transparent image linked via css with a light blue background:
http://jsfiddle.net/lakenney/w0zpmutn/

Comment: Thank you. Your response sent me in the right direction. :)

Comment: My hack worked fine for me for a while. But in my travels over the internet highway, I found something better. I can actually style a paypal buy-now button without using an image. See here: http://www.daddydesign.com/wordpress/how-to-create-a-custom-paypal-button-without-images/

Answer (score 1):

You can use a transparent image as the source to get rid of the border, but then you have no alt-text, but you could overlay some text.

```js
document.querySelector('#input1').onfocus = function() {
    console.log('clicked');
    this.blur();
}
```

```css
label {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 3rem;
    height: 3rem;
    background: blue;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
input {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
}
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<label for="input1">
    <input id="input1" type="image" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ce/Transparent.gif" />
    <a class="overlay" href="#input1">
        Some Text
    </a>
</label>
```

But the form action would no longer work. so you would have to submit the form/redirect the page using javascript.